# illegal text-relocation of function pointer using gfortran on OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm getting the following error messages on my OS X 10.8 system with Xcode 5.0.2 and gfortran 4.8.2 installed via homebrew.

```
% gfortran -shared f03_iso_c.f03
ld: illegal text-relocation to '_compute' in /var/folders/w3/_r4gjs1d363176f99wgkpwl80000gn/T//cc8VFCuI.o from 'anon' in /var/folders/w3/_r4gjs1d363176f99wgkpwl80000gn/T//cc8VFCuI.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The contents of f03_iso_c.f03 are

```
module F03_ISO_C
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

  contains

  integer(c_int) function compute() bind(c) result(compute)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    compute = 1
    return

  end function compute

end module F03_ISO_C

integer function F03_ISO_C_init()
  use F03_ISO_C
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  call USE_FUNC_PTR(c_funloc(compute))

  F03_ISO_C_init = 1
  return

end function F03_ISO_C_init

subroutine USE_FUNC_PTR(f1)
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  type(c_funptr) :: f1

  print *, f1, "is the address"

end subroutine USE_FUNC_PTR
```

Any help resolving this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: This issue has been taken up on the gcc fortran bugzilla site.  You can see the details here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59888

Answer (score 0):

I would say the function compute() is not well written, try this:

```
function compute() bind(c) result(out)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(c_int) :: out

    out = 1
    return

 end function compute
```

Comment: No change.  This gives the same result.

Comment: What difference do you suggest to remedy the "not well written"?  I agree that the code given in the question is not Fortran-compliant, but you make more than one change.